# Preventing reactive block from running when component RE-renders in Svelte

Tags: svelte

How do you prevent component re-render from running the reactive code in the component?

For example, say this is component A.

```
<script>
  $: {
    // Some reactive code with some dependencies (stores).
    // Ex: time intervals, etc.
  }
</script>

// Some HTML
```

Component B renders component A in its markup. There is some logic in component B that makes component A to re-render. This results to the reactive code block in component A to run again, causing it to mess up the time intervals placed.

How do I prevent this from happening?

I want the reactive code block in component A to run only if the variables that it depends on change or if it is the initial render (not when it is re-rendered).

---

**Edit:**

I'm trying to make a desktop app with four pages where one of them is for reminders. Each reminder has its own interval (in minutes). And on every interval, I want it to send a notification; with an option to set a time period for the reminders.

I have a store called `currentTime` that keeps track of the time.
In my `Reminder` component, every minute is checked to see if the time is valid or not (if chose to set a time period).

I also have a store called `currentPage` that keeps track of the current "page".

But when switching between pages, the reactive block runs again, which causes duplicate intervals.

Before switching page:
[Before switching page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8qH6.png)

After switching pages:
[After switching pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHkRo.png)

**Here is the REPL:** https://svelte.dev/repl/80438ddb704c4052b57b469eccca4fdf?version=3.49.0

I'm sure there's a better way than what I'm doing but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If you need to prevent a reactive block from being executed, you are using them the wrong way. Reactive blocks should define *invariants* and be able to run as often and whenever necessary.

Comment: Basically, I'm creating a very simple desktop app with like 4 "pages". But I don't really need any routing per se (hence not using SvelteKit) so I opted to create a page component (component A in my example above) for each of the pages and render the page component depending on the `currentPage` store that simply keeps track of the current page. This `currentPage` store is not used in the reactive block in the page components. But switching to another page and back to the original component leads to the reactive block running again, which is causing my issue. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Add some concrete code to the question along with what you are trying to do (i.e. the explanation in your comment), it still is not clear why you have that reactive block in the first place and what it does. Maybe someone can help then...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I hope the edit provides some clarification.